# Sublime Text Open New Window API

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm writing a sublime text plugin. I'm trying open few files in new window.

In sublime text [API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Window) I found a way to open files with

```
window.open_file(filepath)
```

but I didn't find anything for opening a new window. Can someone please point me to it. I know it's a dumb question but blame it on inadequate documentation :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `new_window` command.

```
sublime.run_command("new_window")
sublime.active_window().open_file(filepath)
```

By the way, you can find lots of useful information via checking the default packages/settings. For example, you can open default key bindings and search "window". You can find `new_window` command. Sublime Text 2 has lots of features which are not documented.

Comment: I looked at so many weird posts and kinda lost all hope of having anything like this http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10777